# Почему в Pygame не меняется параметр 'x' у Rect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, рисование

Не пойму, почему не меняется параметр **`x`** у прямоугольника.

Вот код:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
screen.fill((230,230,230))


rect = pg.draw.rect(screen, ' red', (0, 0, 70, 70))

image_load = pg.image.load('image.png')
image = image_load.get_rect()

def updates():
    rect.x += 1 # не работает

    image.x += 1 # работает
    screen.blit(image_load, image)

while True:

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT or event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
    updates()
    
    pg.display.flip()
```

Он бессмысленный - просто двигает фигуру. Но таким образом я хотел разобраться с атрибутами и посмотреть как всё работает.

В данном случае я могу двигать изображение, меняя его параметр **`x`**, но только не у отрисованного `rect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...

def updates():
    rect.x += 1                                           # работает 

    pg.draw.rect(screen, ' red', (rect.x, 0, 70, 70))     # +++
    
    image.x += 1 # работает
    screen.blit(image_load, image)

...
```

Comment: Я понял идею: сначала создать его вне функции, а потом менять. Спасибо, помогло